# All-in-One Thumbnail Viewer for Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, pdf, thumbnails, psd

I have Windows 7 x64 installed along with Adobe Reader **X**, Photoshop **CS5**, and Illustrator **CS5**. I have noticed that these dont have a thumbnail generated for them. What I need is an All-in-One Thumbnail Viewer for .ai, .psd, .pdf, .eps, etc. I prefer freeware or a registry hack of some sort. I dont want to spend money just to view a thumbnail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found http://www.xnview.com/ does the job perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I feel a better solution is the free SageThumb: https://code.google.com/p/sagethumbs/

I've just installed it and it works well for the formats you list (Win7 x64).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [described here](http://www.techyard.net/enable-thumbnail-view-for-psd-files-in-windows-explorer/).  The article is from 2008 though, so probably predates your version of Photoshop.

It involves downloading a DLL and installing it in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Shell\` as well as running a `.reg` file.